# Spark: CopyToLocal in Cluster Mode

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, hdfs

I have a PySpark Script where data is processed and then converted to CSV files. As the end result should be **ONE** CSV file accessible via WinSCP, I do some additional processing to put the CSV files on the worker nodes together and transfer it out of HDFS to the FTP Server (I think it's called Edge Node).

```
from py4j.java_gateway import java_import
import os
        
YYMM = date[2:7].replace('-','')
        
# First, clean out both HDFS and local folder so CSVs do not stack up (data history is stored in DB anyway if update option is enabled)
os.system('hdfs dfs -rm -f -r /hdfs/path/new/*')
os.system('rm -f /ftp/path/new/*')
        
#timestamp = str(datetime.now()).replace(' ','_').replace(':','-')[0:19]   
df.coalesce(1).write.csv('/hdfs/path/new/dataset_temp_' + date, header = "true", sep = "|")
        
# By default, output CSV has weird name ("part-0000-..."). To give proper name and delete automatically created upper folder, do some more processing
java_import(spark._jvm, 'org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path')
        
sc = spark.sparkContext
fs = spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration())
file = fs.globStatus(sc._jvm.Path('/hdfs/path/new/dataset_temp_' + date + '/part*'))[0].getPath().getName()
fs.rename(sc._jvm.Path('/hdfs/path/new/dataset_temp_' + date + "/" + file), sc._jvm.Path('/hdfs/path/new/dataset_' + YYMM + '.csv'))
fs.delete(sc._jvm.Path('/hdfs/path/new/dataset_temp_' + date), True) 
        
# Shift CSV file out of HDFS into "regular" SFTP server environment
os.system('hdfs dfs -copyToLocal hdfs://<server>/hdfs/path/new/dataset_' + YYMM + '.csv' + ' /ftp/path/new')
```

In Client mode all works fine. But when I switch to Cluster, it gives an Error Message that the final /ftp/path/new in the `CopyToLocal`-Command is not found, I suppose because it is looking on the Worker Nodes and not on the Edge Node. Is there any way to overcome this? As an alternative, I thought to do the final CopyToLocal command from a batch script outside of the Spark Session, but I'd rather have it all in one script...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running the OS commands in your spark script, you can directly write the output out the ftp location. You need to provide the path to the ftp location with savemode set to overwrite. you can then run the code to rename the data after your spark script has completed.

```
YYMM = date[2:7].replace('-','')

df.coalesce(1).write
  .mode("overwrite")
  .csv('/ftp/path/new/{0}'.format(date), header = "true", sep = "|")
```

#run the command below in a separate step once the above code has executed.

```
os.system("mv /ftp/path/new/{0}/*.csv /ftp/path/new/{0}/dataset_' + YYMM + '.csv".format(date))
```

I have made an assumption that the ftp location is accessible by the worker nodes since you are able to run the copyToLOcal command in client mode. If the location is not accessible, you will have to write the file out the hdfs location as before and run the moving of ile and renaming of the file in a separate process/code outsideof the spark script